# Mixed strategy nash equilbrium

Tags: game-theory, nash-equilibrium

In a mixed strategy Nash equilibrium it is always the case that:

a) for each player, each pure strategy that is played with negative probability yields the same expected payoff as the equilibrium mixed strategy itself.

b) for each player, each pure strategy yields the same expected payoff as the equilibrium mixed strategy itself.

c) Each player strictly prefers their mixed strategy to any pure strategy, given that others conform to the equilibrium.

d) For each player, each pure strategy that is played with positive probability yields the same expected payoff as the equilibrium mixed strategy itself.

e) none of the above

Comment: d,  which means that each pure strategy yields the same payoff as that of any of the mixed strategies. it is not b, cause this holds for any of the pure strategies involved in the mixed strategy.

Comment: The question has since been edited entirely (i.e. it's a new question) such that the comment above and my answer are no longer applicable. I have flagged it. I think the edit should be undone and/or the question closed.

Answer (score 0):

- a) makes no sense (you can't put negative probability on an action)
- b) is incorrect. Pure actions that are not played with positive probability in the mix may have arbitrarily bad payoffs since those payoffs never result in any case.
- c) is incorrect. Suppose you did prefer a mix over $a_1,a_2$ (with strictly positive weights on each) to a given pure strategy, $a_1$. Then it must be that the mix gives a higher payoff than $a_1$. But then $a_2$ must give higher payoffs than the mix, as the mix is just a weighted average of $a_1$ and $a_2$.
- d) is correct. To see why, suppose it were not true. Then there would be some pure strategy $a^*$ that you were putting positive probability on in the mix that either gave higher or lower expected payoff than the mix. In the first case (higher), you would then not be willing to put positive weight on other actions -- you would just play $a^*$. In the latter case (lower), you would not be willing to put positive weight on $a^*$.
- e) is incorrect because d) is true.

For future reference, please put a little more context into your questions. That is, tell us what part of it is confusing you, or what you have tried, or any conjectures you might, and in what context you came across this question. Otherwise people may wonder if you're tying to cheat on a test. Now that 4 hours have passed since you asked the question, I'm no longer concerned that I'm helping you cheat on a test.